# как динамический добавлять портфолио на wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, ajax

есть сайт на вордпресс. Натягиваю верстку на вп. Вставил html/css, через редактор вордпресса. Теперь есть блок с портфолио. Она сейчас статична, при нажатии на кнопку через ajax, подгружаются еще картинки. Можно ли сделать так. Что бы как то в админке, пользователь ставил картинку, текст, описание и дублировался html код? Думал сделать, с помощью плагина галереи. Но мне это не очень подходит, да и плюс картинки на странице так и не отображаются, а мне еще и текст с описанием нужно. Есть какие то мысли? Заранее благодарен, за любой ответ

Comment: Отказаться от этого шлака

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Мысли такие, что надо выкинуть html код  из контента и изучать ВП.

Comment: @SeVlad Спасибо

Comment: Самый простой вариант - ACF + кастомный шаблон страницы. Для прмиера https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZKnHQ_2Zos

Comment: @Seredniy имеете ввиду с помощью acf repeater? Не подходит, платно)

Comment: @TricepsSenju тогда CPT + ACF free + CPT archive page + прямые руки

Comment: @Seredniy Спасибо, попробую. А у custom fiels suite, тоже вроде есть повторители, или cpt лучше подойдет?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно почитать о том, что такое объект POST в wordpress. Вам нужно создать кастомный тип поста ПОРТФОЛИО и создать у него дополнительные поля, так как стандартные поля поста вам не подходят (автор поста, дата поста, и т.д это вам не нужно). Это, если я не ошибаюсь, можно сделать и без плагина через стандарнтный API Wordpress, или, как вам предложил @Seredniy использовать плагин ACF, чтобы добавить к вашему новому типа ПОСТА портфолио нужные поля.

Поле это очень широкое понятие. Полем может быть что угодно (картинка портфолио, автор потфолио, строки потфолио и т.д) Все зависит от того, как вы создатите вашу архитектуру.